# Error while Updating/Uninstalling Nuget package manager

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, nuget, package-managers

I am getting an error while updating or uninstalling **Nuget package manager** from **visual studio extensions** and also from **package manager console**.
The error shown is a pop-up box which contains error message-

> "CLR error 8007000e." 
>   The program is terminated.

Can anybody pls help on this.

Comment: Does this error occur only Updating/Uninstalling nuget package manager? The"CLR error 8007000e." errors can occur when your Windows operating system becomes corrupted. You can try to repair this error by Clr Error 8007000e repair tool: http://www.saetechnologies.com/clr-error-8007000e-2/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I am getting this error - The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'developmentDependency' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'copyright, title, language, frameworkAssemblies, summary, iconUrl, dependencies, releaseNotes, licenseUrl, tags, projectUrl, description, references' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd'.

Comment: What did you do to get this error? You need to share us what you have done and some screenshots will be better. Or you can give us some detail steps for what have done so that we can reproduce this issue.

Comment: yes. I went through the following steps-  open visual studio->  tools -> library package manager -> manage nuget packages for solutions  -> then i search Nuget in the Online section.     Then I tried to install Nuget.CommandLine v3.5.0,,,  and then a pop-up appears with the above error.

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio and NuGet? It`s works fine on my Visual Studio 2015 update 3 and NuGet version is 3.5.0.1996. Since above issue is not related to the previous issue, I suggest you can submit a new post for above issue with more detail info and screenshots, more community members and MVP on Visual C++ forum may further look at your issue and provide more suggestions.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for your reply